# Using AppendChild on an svg in Internet Explorer is doing the wrong thing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I've run into problems with this gem:

```
function CmdRefresh(cmd) {
    var svg = document.createElement('svg');
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 3200 1800");
    svg.setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth);
    svg.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight);
    var x = 160;
    for (var i = 0; i < cmd.Cards.length; i++) {
        var suit = Math.floor(cmd.Cards[i] / 13);
        var rank = cmd.Cards[i] % 13;
        var card = "CDHS"[suit] + "A23456789TJQK"[rank];

        var img = document.createElement('image')
        img.setAttribute("width", 505);
        img.setAttribute("height", 707);
        img.setAttribute("x", x + i * 225);
        img.setAttribute("y", 676);
        img.setAttribute("href", "/img/Card_" + card + ".svg");

        svg.appendChild(img);
    }
    document.body.innerHTML = svg.outerHTML;
}
```

I'm deliberately sticking with vanilla JavaScript for this project. It works fine in Chrome. I get this in the output:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 3200 1800" width="1920" height="551">
    <image width="505" height="707" x="160" y="676" href="/img/Card_C9.svg"></image>
    <image width="505" height="707" x="385" y="676" href="/img/Card_D3.svg"></image>
    ....
</svg>
```

Which is what I expected (I left out the bulk of the *image* tags). It does not work in Edge. Edge turns "image" into "img" which fails. This bug was acknowledged in Aug 2016 and still hasn't been fixed. (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8545675/)  I tried again with Internet Explorer, which *showed* this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3200 1800" width="1920" height="911"></svg>
<img width="505" height="707" x="160" y="676" href="/img/Card_C9.svg" />
....
```

But editing the tag in Internet Explorer shows this (scroll to see the end tag not enclosing the children):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3200 1800" width="1920" height="911" />
```

Clearly this tag can't have children. What's the solution here? Say "screw it" to using createElement() et al? Have I made a mistake? Did Microsoft make another? Can someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use createElement to create SVG elements in Explorer, you must use createElementNS i.e.

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
```

for svg elements, and

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image')
```

for image elements.

In Explorer's day they all worked that way i.e. createElement was for HTML elements only. So many people got this wrong that newer browsers have adjusted createElement to create SVG elements in SVG documents and HTML elements in HTML documents rather than always creating HTML elements.

Explorer will also require you to create href attributes in the xlink namespace with the setAttributeNS method.

```
img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', "/img/Card_" + card + ".svg");
```

Finally I expect that Explorer will not support using innerHTML to create SVG elements, you'd need to simply append your SVG with appendChild, that would be more efficient even in modern browsers as you're avoiding serialising everything to a string and back again. Something like

```
document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. While I knew innerHTML wasn't going to work, I succumbed to the temptation to treat SVG as HTML, not XML. I'll give it a go when I get home. That might also get around Edge's img/image bug.